# How to add image from Database in Crystal Report viewer?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Hello I have saved an image in my database field and want to display that image in my crystal report viewer but unable to figure out how to perform it? Any help or suggestion will  be very helpful.

Comment: http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2012/06/crystal-reports-display-images-database.html

Comment: There is no use in getting tensed.This is an community where people help you to solve problem if you have any. Explain what you have tried and these types of questions can just be solved by searching in google.i gave you the link from google too.FYI i didnot downvote

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I was using SQLite and important thing that is to be done is to create
1.) A BLOB field to save your data is to be used.

2.) Use the following code to select the file. For this one need to call the Open Dialog Box.

```
{ 

OpenFileDialog of1 = new OpenFileDialog();

of1.Filter = "JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg";

of1.ShowDialog();

tbImage.Text = of1.FileName;

}
```

Note: Don't forget to set the related Database Field type as System.byte[];

3.) Now convert the file into Byte Stream.
    {

```
byte[] imageBt = null;

FileStream fstream = new FileStream(tbImage.Text,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);

BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);

imageBt = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);

}
```

4.) Insert the image in the database

```
{
String query = "Insert into Employee Values (" + e1.EmpID + ",'" + e1.FirstName + "','" + e1.LastName + "','" + e1.EmailAddress + "', @IMG)";

myCommand = new SQLiteCommand(query, dbConn);

myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@IMG", e1.Image));
}
```

For Retrieval of the images first an ImageBox is required

1.) Use the following code to get the BLOB data byte and to place the image in the Image Box
    {

```
MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream((byte[])(reader["Image"]));

ImageBox.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mstream);

}
```